# html5 audio recording on desktop safari

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari

Are there any way of recording audio on desktop safari browser in html5/JS? Most other browsers support getUserMedia() for accessing microphone devices and unfortunately safari doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like it's not possible probably for security reasons ? Anyway I would really love if there was a way to do it! :)

Comment: Html5 web audio doesn't have great support across common browsers (yet) and the permission dialogs are easy to miss by users. We end up implementing Flash audio recording which works consistently across all browsers.

Comment: Problem is Safari is not supporting flash, so were back were we started. I'm looking also for real time recordring support for Safari

Comment: Safari on desktop (PC/Mac) supports Flash.